# Geoserver CQL query using Java

Tags: java, rest, geoserver

I have two layers of shape file(shape file contains the geographical information of particular area) in GeoServer, I am able to filter specific place like california using this CQL query:

```
(INTERSECTS(col1,querySingle('layerName','col1','filterParam=value')))
```

on the GeoServer UI. I want to do the same using Java/REST API. Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.